# Python Class variable not keeping value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I declared a class with a class variable. 
Module name my_moudle_1.py
For example:

```
class my_class:
    my_dict={}#The class variable

def __init__(self):
   return
```

In a different module - my_moudle_2.py i wrote:

from my_moudle_1 import my_class

Inside this module there is a class. In the class method i wrote:

my_class.my_dict['123']=5

In third module - my_moudle_3.py i wrote again:

from my_moudle_1 import my_class

When i am checking the my_dict variable value in the instance of my_class, i get
that the value is {}.
How can i update in a different module the class variable and use it 
inside an instance in a different file?

Thanks

Comment: Could it be the indentation?

Comment: It would make it easier for people to help you if you were to post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

That shouldn't be the case. I can't reproduce this problem:

## mymod.py

```
class my_class:
    my_dict = {}

    def __init__(self):
       return

my_class.my_dict['foo'] = 'bar'
```

## mymod2.py

```
from mymod import my_class

my_class.my_dict['greeting'] = 'Hello'
```

## testapp.py

```
from mymod import my_class
import mymod2  # will modify my_dict as a side effect

my_class.my_dict['barq'] = 'foo'

print(my_class.my_dict)
```

---

```
$ python3 testapp.py
{'foo': 'bar', 'greeting': 'Hello', 'barq': 'foo'}
$
```

Comment: Updating the class variable in another module and class and trying to read the class variable in another class and module returns {}

Comment: @Orenl Updated the example. Still unable to repro.

Comment: if you can't reproduce, then don't answer, just vote to close as "cannot reproduce"

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre The answer was "That shouldn't be the case". The non-repro steps illuminate how things work.